# .wixproj type of file not opening in *.sln

Tags: wix

I am working on a VS2010 solution with .NET Framework 4.0. My machine is running Windows 7.

I have a `.VBPROJ` file in the solution. However whenever I open it I receive the following error:

> .wixproj type of file not supported by this version of application

Please let me know if WIX software or some other software installation has to be done for this or if it should have been included with Visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

Windows installer xml ... just install it

https://wixtoolset.org/releases/

Comment: Due to constraints imposed by Microsoft, using a .wixproj in Visual Studio requires a non-Express version of Visual Studio. You can always build a .wixproj with MSBuild. See [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) for an alternative IDE.